# investigating bsod causes

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod, debug

I experienced my second bsod in two weeks and I am starting to worry, here is the dump from the latest crash, can anyone gather any interesting information here?

In the hopes of preventing this in the future I have installed some new drivers: video, mouse .. and removed some software by ASUS AI Suite.

When the crash occurred I was running the following applications: postgres 9.2x64 server, pgadmin, VLC player w/ opengl rendering, world of warcraft(directx), google chrome, SWTOR launcher/downloader, outlook, virtual box w/ w7(active)

system details:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          trip
Registered Organization:
Original Install Date:     11/17/2012, 1:20:01 PM
System Boot Time:          1/24/2013, 9:35:44 PM
System Manufacturer:       Asus
System Model:              Z77 Sabertooth
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9 GenuineIntel ~3501 Mhz
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. 1504, 8/3/2012
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     16,335 MB
Available Physical Memory: 13,047 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  32,668 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 28,717 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    3,951 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Hotfix(s):                 122 Hotfix(s) Installed.
```

dump details:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except,
it must be protected by a Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it
is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff900c3010d90, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffff96000239e36, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 0000000000000000, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS:  fffff900c3010d90 Paged session pool

FAULTING_IP: 
win32k!IsThreadHung+22
fffff960`00239e36 488b8170010000  mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+170h]

MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  0

IMAGE_NAME:  win32k.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  50aeecc6

MODULE_NAME: win32k

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff960000d0000 win32k

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x50

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff880028cc710 -- (.trap 0xfffff880028cc710)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=000000000f99a027 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffff900c3010c20
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff96000239e36 rsp=fffff880028cc8a0 rbp=000000000000000f
 r8=00009fddc3f269c2  r9=fffff880028cc930 r10=00000000009fddc3
r11=000000000f99a027 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
win32k!IsThreadHung+0x22:
fffff960`00239e36 488b8170010000  mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+170h] ds:fffff900`c3010d90=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002e76eec to fffff80002ecefc0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`028cc5a8 fffff800`02e76eec : 00000000`00000050 fffff900`c3010d90 00000000`00000000 fffff880`028cc710 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`028cc5b0 fffff800`02ecd0ee : 00000000`00000000 fffff900`c3010d90 fffff880`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x4514f
fffff880`028cc710 fffff960`00239e36 : fffffa80`0f4fa500 00000000`0000001b 00000000`00000000 fffff880`03317100 : nt!KiPageFault+0x16e
fffff880`028cc8a0 fffff960`0020f906 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 fffff960`003b6740 fffff900`c011fa18 : win32k!IsThreadHung+0x22
fffff880`028cc8d0 fffff960`0023a448 : fffff900`c06b2040 00000000`0000000f 00000000`0000000c fffff900`c011fa18 : win32k!IsHungWindow+0x1a
fffff880`028cc900 fffff960`00194bdd : fffff900`c2d838e0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000004 fffff800`02ed7e33 : win32k!xxxHungAppDemon+0x68
fffff880`028cc960 fffff960`0019565b : 00000000`00000000 fffff960`003b6f10 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000001 : win32k!TimersProc+0xf1
fffff880`028cc9b0 fffff960`00125148 : fffffa80`0000007b 00000000`0000000f fffff880`00000001 ffffffff`80000348 : win32k!RawInputThread+0x9ab
fffff880`028cca80 fffff960`001a5e9a : fffffa80`00000002 fffff880`028aae00 00000000`00000020 00000000`00000000 : win32k!xxxCreateSystemThreads+0x58
fffff880`028ccab0 fffff800`02ece253 : fffffa80`0f62d060 00000000`00000004 000007ff`fffd3000 00000000`00000000 : win32k!NtUserCallNoParam+0x36
fffff880`028ccae0 000007fe`fd8f1eea : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`0310fc78 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x000007fe`fd8f1eea


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
win32k!IsThreadHung+22
fffff960`00239e36 488b8170010000  mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+170h]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32k!IsThreadHung+22

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_win32k!IsThreadHung+22

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_win32k!IsThreadHung+22

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the information provided, it seems its a memory problem (RAM, main memory, L2, Video RAM, ...) when it tries to read it. The failure happens when either the SO or program tryies to read a zone of memory and it doesn't find it, either because its out of bounds or because the zone is empty and should contain data.

If the failure happens when you run all of the above programs, then it maybe be a problem with the RAM, since you might be allocating a lot of it and the physical RAM might have a zone with problems, hence the failure. You can check this part by doing a Memtest for several hours and check if there's any error on the tests.

Comment: Yea, im dragging my feet regarding the memtest, i'll run it sunday night :(